# Aggregate PARTITION BY 3 columns, one being year. Adds multiple projects in every year after first

Tags: sql-server

I have gotten help from the community to build a query that gives me accumulated amount by project and company for each period until today. It also makes sure that if there are no records in a period it will leave 0 instead of skipping that period.
Now I'm trying to add partition by year into this in order to get year-to-date numbers. It seems to work fine for the first year, however second year it adds (in my sample) both projects togehter.

Fiddle for this example is here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d00caa265d67f4702a31c1f011ebe058

This is my code:

```
;WITH total_range AS 
(
  SELECT Comp, project, datecol = MIN(datecol), Yr
    FROM GLProject
    GROUP BY Comp, project, Yr
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Comp, project, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, datecol), Yr = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, datecol))
  FROM total_range 
  WHERE datecol < @d
  )
SELECT 
  tr.project, tr.Comp, 
  amount = SUM(SUM(coalesce(p.amount, 0))) 
  OVER (
             PARTITION BY tr.comp, tr.project, tr.Yr ORDER BY tr.datecol
 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
           ), 
  period = CONVERT(char(6), tr.datecol, 112)
FROM total_range AS tr
LEFT OUTER JOIN GLProject AS p 
ON concat(tr.Comp, tr.project) = concat(p.Comp, p.project)
AND tr.datecol = p.datecol
group by tr.Comp, tr.project, tr.datecol, tr.Yr
```

Output for 202101 (January) is accumulated sum (10+10) of both projects. I would like it to be just Year-to-date for each project individually.

Example output

| project | Comp | amount | period | Yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | AA | 20 | 202101 | 2021 |
| 12345 | AA | 40 | 202102 | 2021 |
| 99999 | AA | 20 | 202101 | 2021 |
| 99999 | AA | 40 | 202102 | 2021 |

What I would like my example output to be is:

| project | Comp | amount | period | Yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | AA | 10 | 202101 | 2021 |
| 12345 | AA | 20 | 202102 | 2021 |
| 99999 | AA | 10 | 202101 | 2021 |
| 99999 | AA | 20 | 202102 | 2021 |

Hope it's just a small thing I'm missing.

Thanks for alle the great help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `total_range` includes duplicates before you've grouped or otherwise filtered them out, so their amounts are counting double. By making all of the amounts `10` (and then grouping *later*) you've kind of hidden this from yourself. This is more apparent if you just mess with a couple of numbers, like [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c1296de7d311b972eb8f1f48349e6e6), or by just adding row numbers to the output of the very first CTE, like [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8f40a184e39a206124603a3a34ddbbd).

One way to remove the duplicates that come out of the recursive `UNION ALL` is to simply have a second CTE that groups first (you could also add a row number there and filter on rn = 1 next).

```
DECLARE @d date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), 1);

;WITH raw_range AS 
(
  SELECT Comp, project, datecol = MIN(datecol)
    FROM GLProject
    GROUP BY Comp, project, DATEPART(YEAR, datecol)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Comp, project, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, datecol)
  FROM raw_range 
  WHERE datecol < @d
),
total_range AS 
(
  SELECT Comp, project, datecol,  
         Yr = DATEPART(YEAR, datecol)
  FROM raw_range
  GROUP BY Comp, project, datecol
)
SELECT tr.project, 
       tr.Comp, 
       amount = SUM(COALESCE(p.amount,0)) OVER 
                (PARTITION BY tr.Comp, tr.Project, tr.Yr 
                 ORDER BY tr.datecol),
       period = tr.datecol
FROM total_range AS tr
LEFT JOIN dbo.GLProject AS p
  ON tr.project = p.project
 AND tr.Comp    = p.Comp
 AND tr.datecol = p.datecol
ORDER BY tr.Comp, tr.project, tr.datecol;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=827375f9dc6b993159ab8c16e3491a0d)

Note you still don't need `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, you still don't need nested `SUM(SUM())`, and you still don't need `GROUP BY` on the final output. And I'm not sure why you need a separate `Yr` column on the source table, since you can always find the year from a date, so the information is redundant. I'd also stay away from relying on `CONCAT()` to, uh, "simplify" joins, since `CONCAT('A', null, 'BC') === CONCAT('AB', 'C', null)`.

Comment: Great! Thanks again @Aaron Bertrand!
Also thanks for describing the issue as this helps my understanding of writing sql queries. 
I had to add back Sum(Sum()) and Group BY at the end, because otherswise I got duplicate periods if there were more than one transaction in that period.